# Django add middleware that show form on each request

Tags: python, django, request, httpresponse, django-middleware

I am new to this django middleware I worked with django middleware by adding login page on each selected requested page. But now I want to show a html form as user request any page. So what should I use process_view or process_response to call the template (i.e html form).

add a form that takes input from user yes or no if its yes then go to the view page else show HttpResponseForbidden(). And next time if user had saved yes earlier then skip this form.

Comment: Do you want to add a loader during request to process in your front-end ? If so , this should be front-end responsibility.

Comment: @Shakil not loader but I need to add a form that takes input from user yes or no if its yes then show the view page else show HttpResponseForbidden().